# Google: log in on a new machine without a phone

Tags: passwords, google, phone

Trying to log into my google account from a new computer, I had no choice but to use my phone in order to connect, the options were:

- use something like a "Security by Google" *smartphone application*
- receive a code by *sms*
- get a *call*
- read a code deep into *Android* parameters.
- or *abort* connection

The thing is that, *connecting to Google* and *having my phone* are not forever-absolute-concommitent events. Especially if I am trying to log from a new machine, because the reason I need it may be the same reason I do not have a phone at the moment.

**Is there any way I can ensure that my password is the only thing I will ever need in the future to connect to Google *via* any machine in the world?**

Interestingly:

- I have never had my « number verified » as I have been prompted many times by Google Accounts.
- I have never activated the « two steps validation » in Google Security parameters.

Comment: "Is there any way I can ensure that my password is the only thing I will ever need in the future to connect to Google via any machine in the world?" That's not really a question for Information Security StackExchange. Maybe try [su] or [webapps.se]. If you're curious about why Google is displaying this prompt and what security benefit it provides though, we'd be happy to help.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is too old to migrate.

Comment: If you don’t want enhanced logon security you can turn it off, I would not do that. Print yourself some of the emergency codes to be ready in case your mfa devices are lost.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this is a misunderstanding on your part of the importance of this additional security measure.

Might I introduce you to this site: https://haveibeenpwned.com/

This website, run by a Mr. Troy Hunt, keeps track of major data breaches and provides a service to see if you've ever been a part of one. If you had an account on a site that might be insecure (ie, Yahoo) and shared the same password on yahoo with Google then a hacker could effectively have your password.

Your password is effectively an authorization measure that grants access based on **"something you know"**. More specifically, it's supposed to be **"something that *only you* know"**.

If someone could steal your password from one of these data breaches or by any other means then you lose that ability to identify yourself. By requiring your phone to log in (in cases where the request came from a new device or new location) you can help protect the account of those who might've have their password stolen.

The phone is **"something you have"** which means that in addition to gaining knowledge (your password) that you're supposed to only have, they have to have physical access to something that only you should have (your phone).

Oftentimes, security measures end up detracting from user experience. Obviously there are cases where you won't be able to access your phone and it can be stressful. Google does offer an "offline" solution to this. You can set up "Backup Codes" for your Google account. When you set this up, it'll create a little notecard pdf (that you're supposed to print out and carry in your wallet/purse/etc) with 10 separate, 1-time-use codes on it that you can use whenever you need to log in with two factor.

Here's where you can go to set it up. Go to https://myaccount.google.com/security. After that, select 2-Step Verification.

[image: Two Factor Authentication - Backup Codes]

---

I would enable two step verification so you can use backup codes in place of this phone-based verification. Additionally, enable two step verification on other services as well.

Comment: Is this an option usable for signing in to new computers as well?  Context: I don't keep a smart phone on me, and Google makes it hard for me to access my account on new computers, which I do fairly often thanks to my not maintaining a smart phone.

Comment: @frank as far as I'm aware you should be able to use backup codes when authenticating into new systems.

Answer (score 1):

> I mean come on! This is my password, you should not need anything more! I may loose it to any user I want if I wish, and I will not if I wish not.

There is a sheer number of users *losing* their passwords every day. Not allowing anyone to suddenly connect from the other side of the world from where it usually does is actually a strong security measure. I gather that it is actually the change of location what prompted this.

And unlike other service providers, Google is keen enough of actually telling you the next time that it blocked a login attempt, from which IP address it came, and to let you mark it as legit.

Connecting through a VPN (or similar) that exits through a place considered *normal* (eg. from your country if you are abroad) will usually allow you to overcome this. Also, if a session is already open in the device, it won't require you going through these hoops (and it will learn it is ok).

Thus, I would recommend a VPN service as an attempt for *the only thing you will ever need in the future to connect to Google via any machine in the world*, although only Google higher-ups could really make you such a promise.

(at the risk of slightly bending your requirements, I encourage you to use a *different* password for the VPN!)

PS: Note that Google Authenticator actually uses [TOTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6238), so you could use other implementations.